# How to hide HTML elements without taking space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML paragraph that initially i want to be hidden.Later On a click event i want that to show or display where someother paragraph is present this time by hiding that.But when i am trying to set visibility property to hidden ,that time also paragraph is taking space and height ,width that i dont want ..

Here is the sample paragraph ..

```
<div id="TeamsDesc" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <p id="Billing" style="float:left;color: #666666; width:700px; font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border-right: thin dotted #666666; line-height: 18px;">

             Paragraph Contents

            </p>
</div>
```

If i am adding this at the end of the webpage that time it is increasing the height of the webpage that is not desired..

Comment: Oh, yay inline styles! Anyway, replace visibility: hidden; with display: none;

Comment: please avoid using inline styles. it adds duplicate code, makes your code unreadable and difficult to work with for others. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

With `visibility:hidden` the element will not be visible, but it'll be rendered and it'll take up corresponding space, with `display:none` the element will be there in `DOM` , but won't be rendered at all and won't take up space.

*Update as per comments*

```
$('button').click(function(){
 $('#para1').hide();
 $('#Billing').show();
})
```

Comment: How to show it on Button click by hiding other element .Please see my updated post

Comment: Do you want to show/hide it on click of a button..? not sure what exactly you want to do from question, can you make it more clear..?

Comment: Yes i want to hide a paragraph with id "para1" and show this div "Billing" on button click.How to achieve this?

Comment: One Doubt sir How can i add this element to another div which has id of "#BodyDesc" because i want this hidden element to show at specific location which is defined in DIV

Comment: Which element, the paragraph `#para1` or the div `#billing`..? and when, on button click..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54432/discussion-between-user3664608-and-t-j).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:none` instead of `visibility: hidden` if you do not want the element to take space when not shown. To show the element you will need to `display:block`

```
<div id="TeamsDesc" style="display: none;">
    <p id="Billing" style="float:left;color: #666666; width:700px; font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border-right: thin dotted #666666; line-height: 18px;">Paragraph Contents</p>
</div>
```

Some of possible values of [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
display: none    
display: inline
display: block   
display: inline-block  
display: inherit
```

You can read more about display [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)